# How can I avoid res.render() generating '&quot ' when parsing an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js beginner here.

When parsing an array from server to client res.render() (as far as I understand) replaces quotation marks with `'&quot'` elements like this:

[image: My topics var on client side]

Part of index.pug that creates the variable:

```
var topics = #{topics};
```

Part of index.js that creates and parses the variable:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var data = [];

    papers.getAllTopics(function(err, content) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i<content.length; i++){
                data.push(content[i].TOPIC);
            }
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(data);
            // res.send(data);
        }
        res.render('index', { title: 'Xintra | Home', "topics": data});
    });
});
```

If I remove `data = JSON.stringify(data);` then the variables arrive in this form as unexpected identifiers: 
[image]

How do I avoid this happening and what's the best practice for parsing arrays from the server to client?

Comment: Could you please try `var topics = !{topics};`? This should not escape the input

Comment: Probably shouldn't be using pug to dynamically render JavaScript. Instead you should be using a JSON endpoint where you can request the array as JSON from the client-side, rather than generating on page-load embedded in a `<script>` tag somewhere.

Comment: @Luca is correct, see here for more usage information: http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping, echoing unescaped data in jade or pug can be done by replacing

```
var topics = #{topics};
```

with

```
var topics = !{topics};
```

This should give you the desired output.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you